# AngularJS - Templates : ngInclude directive

Tags: angularjs

My templates contain JS, as they are called JS is not executed, you have an idea please.

For example in my JS file script.js, i have methods that apply to HTML elements in my templtes and it does not work, an idea please.

Example :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <ng-include src="'header.html'"></ng-include>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">AngularJs</div>
<div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav').html('<ul><li><a href="">Link<a></li></ul>');
});
```

The script execute well, I feel it does not find the element div#nav.

Comment: Could you please give some details? The core sample of html file that you try to include with `ngInclude`, for example.

Comment: I am updating the post with an example, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I read wrong a part of your question, my mistake.

The DOM ready statement of jQuery will probably not work correctly. What you can do is on your  ngInclude tag add a onload="FUNCTION_NAME" that contains the DOM edition you indicated inside the script.js

For more information have a look at the documentation here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/docs-1.0.1/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

--- Old Post ---

@YoussefElMontaser, you don't have to put the quotes on the ngInclude:

```
<ng-include src="header.html"></ng-include>
```

probably that is what is wrong with your script not going forward.
Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, without the quotes in the file name does not work

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i will edit my post with a possible solution

Comment: I added a function myFunction and it does not work, function `myFunction(){ $('#nav').html('<ul><li><a href="">Link<a></li></ul>'); }` 

`<ng-include src="'header.html'" onload='myFunction'></ng-include>`

Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example based on the example of official anguarjs:
http://jsfiddle.net/HVzgX/ . Thank you

Comment: Great, i found the solution, http://jsfiddle.net/esjeY/

@guiligan, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

The solution provided by Youssef can be made "more Angular", and it will not require jQuery:

```
<!-- template2.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    <p ng-class="color">Content of template2.html</p>
</script>

$scope.myFunction = function() {
    $scope.color = 'red';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/MfHa6/

In the Angular world, we try to change model properties (e.g., $scope.color) and let the view update automatically.  We try to not look up elements by ID or jQuery selectors, and we try to avoid DOM manipulation in the controller -- e.g., $('#tpl2').addClass('red');

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/esjeY/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
            <option value="">(blank)</option>
        </select>
        url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    </div>
    <div ng-include src="template.url" onload='myFunction()'></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.templates = [{
        name: 'template1.html',
        url: 'template1.html'
    }, {
        name: 'template2.html',
        url: 'template2.html'
    }];

    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.myFunction = function() {

        $('#tpl2').addClass('red');            
    }
}
```

@guiligan : Thanks for your help.